# Escaping quote in firebird isql result

Tags: sql, bash, firebird, firebird2.5

I have simple bash scripts that query one Firebird database with isql and pipes the results to isql connected to another database.  The first result set is of the form UPDATE ... or INSERT ... and the second isql executes those.
Up to now the data has always been numeric; now I have to deal with names which may contain an embedded quote.  This causes the input to the second isql to be invalid.
What is the simplest way to make sure a single quote (in a name, not the total result set) is doubled?

```
UPDATE FOO SET NAME='O'CONNOR' WHERE ...;
```

should be

```
UPDATE FOO SET NAME='O''CONNOR' WHERE ...;
```

The bash code is

```
(isql -i update.sql server:db1; echo "COMMIT;") | egrep "^UPDATE|^COMMIT"|isql -e server2:db2
```

Where the update.sql result set is the update command shown above.
And no, I'm not worried about little Bobby Tables :)

Comment: Do you have a question?  You seem to understand what to do.

Comment: Can you include the commands your running?  This is going to make it easier to see what is going on..  Isn't it fb-isql?  isql can conflict with the unixodbc package.

Comment: My question is how to make update statement #1 look like #2 when piped to the second isql.  I can't figure out how to have the first result set escape the embedded quote, or how to have bash figure out there is an embedded quote that must be escaped before piping to isql.

Comment: What about using [`replace`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-replace) in whatever you do to generate those statements to double the quotes?

Answer (score 3):

Mark Rotteveel kindly pointed out that I forgot about the Firebird function`REPLACE (str, find, repl)` to replace single quotes in the result set with double quotes.